# При изменение или редактирования любого поля определенной....

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Помогите пожалуйста, все облазил, нужно что бы при изменение любого элемента формы, кнопка "Сохранить" была доступной(able), иначе кнопка не доступная (disabled). Думал сделать на JS, событие onChange - не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formId").change(function(){
        $("#submitForm").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```